# set_header in MY_Controller codeigniter 3 not working

Tags: codeigniter

I have extending ci_controller like this on application/core

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
}

}

class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller {
   public $layout = 'layout';

}  

class Surveyor_Controller extends MY_Controller {

 public $layout = 'surveyor/template/layout';

 public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $login_status = $this->session->userdata('login_status');
    $group = $this->session->userdata('group');

    if (($login_status !== true) && ($group !== 3)) {
        redirect(base_url());
    }

    // Pastikan hanya "operator" yang boleh mengakses.
    if ($group !== '3') {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Anda tidak berhak mengakses halaman ini!');
        redirect(base_url());
    }
  }
```

}

My question is, back arrow page is still working 
So, in application/controller : i made a new class like this :

```
class C_surveyor extends Surveyor_Controller {

public $data = array(
    'halaman' => 'home',
    'main_view' => 'surveyor/v_home'
);

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('m_surveyor');
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);
}
```

Just say user has on index, and clik arrow back so get login page. Header not working. When user click right arraow, it still get index page.
Where am I missing ?
Any solution it so appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code instead of that 2 lines,

```
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $last_update).' GMT');
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Refer [This](http://www.robertmullaney.com/2011/08/13/disable-browser-cache-easily-with-codeigniter/)